# Moving ASP.NET Identity EF users to a new database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity-2

I was tasked to re-write a server currently running in Azure. This server is very badly written, exposes an API that is badly designed, and overall the model design itself was sub-par.

My task was mainly to streamline this, remove features and add new features. This resulted in a brand new server I will have to deploy soon.

However the client would like to preserve the current user base. The current design is simple: IdentityUsers are slightly customized (added an extra Id I'll be dropping), and actual user data is stored in a separate table, with a separate model (the added Id is a reference to this model).

I've unified the users, and would like to preserve their UserName, Email properties, and if possible, their passwords. However I guess the latter won't be possible due to the hashing.

Is there a simple way of doing this, or should I just export these properties, and create new users with new passwords (and of course notify them in e-mail about the need to change their passwords)?

Comment: Can you use same hashing algorithm to check passwords after the migration, and implement some kind of safety check, where they will be prompted to create a new password upon the next login? You can then store new password in a separate column until process is done

Comment: The hashing algorithm is the built-in one, which generates the hash salt upon first run of the code, if it does not exist yet. However I'm not sure where it is stored and how. I don't think the new server code can replicate it.